# How to display wide table in the output in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I would like to output all columns (there are 20 of them), but with the settings it turns out like this, it’s not beautiful .. Please tell me how to expand the output area so that all columns fit and do not cover each other.

I tried to change the wide, result is the same.
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSnCl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n61Yx.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Besides `max_columns`, your problem is in the `print` statement: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/49446624.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `pd.set_option('max_columns', None)`

Comment: Yes,     I used: pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 20)
    pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)